# Javascript - Sanitize Malicious code from file (string)

Tags: javascript, security, sanitization

I have a data javascript file, which is being dynamically added to website via some custom code.
This file comes from a third party vendor, who could potentially add malicious code in the file

Before this file is added to the website, I would like to parse through it, and look for malicious code, such as redirects or alerts, that inherently get executed upon a files inclusion in the project/website.

For example, my js file could look like this :

```
alert ('i am malicious');
var IAmGoodData = 
[
{ Name :'test', Type:'Test2 },
{ Name :'test1', Type:'Test21' },
{ Name :'test2', Type:'Test22' }
]
```

I load this file into a object via a XMLHttpRequest call, and when this call returns, I can use the variable (which is my file text) and search it for words:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'folder/fileName.js');

client.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
        ScanText(client.responseText);
}
client.send();

function ScanText(text)
{
        alert(text);
        var index = text.search('alert');  //Here i can search for keywords
}
```

The last line would return index of 0, as the word alert is found at index 0 in the file.

Questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to search for keywords in the file?
2. What specific keywords should i be searching for to prevent malicious code being run? ie redirects, popups, sounds etc.....

Comment: Your approach is useless. You will never be able to detect every possible malicious action. You need to reconsider how you're doing things. Perhaps provide more context on what this file is and how you need to use it?

Comment: Javascript is dynamic enough that this is _extremely_ difficult.  Use Google Caja.

Comment: @DarkFalcon It is a file that is fileld with map nodes and info (location, name etc..) about those nodes.  We display them on a map.  These nodes are delivered to us via a third party.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the recommendation i will look up Google Caja. in the mean time, do you have any examples of malicious code?

Comment: And when they compress/compact/encode the file how would you be able to detect that?

Comment: `eval("a"+"lert(1)");` etc...

Comment: Basically you need to trust the third party or do not use it.

Comment: Instead of having them include `var IAmGoodData = `, make them simply provide JSON (which is *basically* what the rest of the file is, or seems to be). Then you parse it as JSON - `JSON.parse()`. If it fails, they either didn't follow the JSON format well, or have external code, and in either case you would ignore the response

Comment: @Ian  The nodes are in JSON format already.  Could you write up a answer on parsing JSON data from inside javascript code?  I will mark your answer as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @jordan.peoples Cool, just added an answer. Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having them include `var IAmGoodData =`, make them simply provide JSON (which is *basically* what the rest of the file is, or seems to be). Then you parse it as JSON, using `JSON.parse()`. If it fails, they either didn't follow the JSON format well, or have external code, and in either case you would ignore the response.

For example, you'd expect data from the external file like:

```
[
{ Name :'test', Type:'Test2' },
{ Name :'test1', Type:'Test21' },
{ Name :'test2', Type:'Test22' }
]
```

which needs to be properly serialized as JSON (double quotes instead of single quotes, and double quotes around the keys). In your code, you'd use:

```
var json;
try {
    json = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
catch (ex) {
    // Invalid JSON
}

if (json) {
    // Do something with the response
}
```

Then you could loop over `json` and access the `Name` and `Type` properties of each.

*Random Note:*

In your `client.onreadystatechange` callback, make sure you check `client.readyState === 4 && client.status === 200`, to know that the request was successful and is done.

Comment: Hey Ian, What does setting the readyState and status of the client object do explicitly? Is there a listing of the states and status and what they mean somewhere?

Comment: Also, i cannot seem to get the JSON.parse to ever work, it always falls through into the catch clause.  Is there something i have to include to use it?

Comment: Oops nevermind, it was just picking up incorrect json and failing.  The problem is even when i just have json data, it still doesn't work.  it sees the first name node and bombs

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely difficult to do. There are no intrinsically *malicious* keywords or functions in JavaScript, there are malicious *applications*. You could be getting false positives for "malicious" activity and prevent a legitimate code with a real purpose from being executed. And at the same time, anyone with a little bit of imagination could bypass any "preventive" method you may implement.

I'd suggest you look for a different approach. This is one of those problems (like CAPTCHA) in which it's trivial for a human to solve while for a machine is practically impossible to do so. You could try having a moderator or some human evaluator to interpret the code and accept it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info.  This file only consists of data nodes for a map.  There will never be the case where we will have legitimate code with a real purpose.  So i can safley search for code and if found, always assume its malicious

Comment: @jordan.peoples Ah, I thought it was code in general. Then I'd suggest, instead of "black listing" all the possible malicious code, "white listing" what it is that you expect. For example, using a RegEx to match data nodes, and if it _does_ match it _then_ accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have them provide valid JSON rather than arbitrary Javascript.
You can then call `JSON.parse()` to read their data without any risk of code execution.

In short, **data is not code**, and should not be able to contain code.

Comment: We all know this, but what if the other group turns malicious (like getting fired, which happens everyday) and on their last upload they change the data file to contain code, as it is simply text.... what then huh?

Comment: @jordan.peoples: That's exactly why you should always treat as text, so that it _cannot_ contain code.

Comment: anything can contain code and everything is text in javascript.

Comment: @jordan.peoples: As long as you never _treat_ it as code – never call `eval`, and always concatenate safely, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't. The user should be allowed to type whatever they want, and it's your job to display it.

It all depends on where it is being put, of course:

- Database: `mysql_real_escape_string` or equivalent for whatever engine you're using.
- HTML: `htmlspecialchars` in PHP, `createTextNode` or `.replace(/</g,"&lt;")` in JavaScript
- JavaScript: `json_encode` in PHP, `JSON.stringify` in JavaScript.

At the end of the day, just [don't be Yahoo](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)